# ListView dynamic styling react-native

Tags: listview, react-native, react-native-listview

In my project, I'm trying to change background color of my ListView.
The colour are already inside an array and inside the component will mound I first get the rand number so that everytime user open the component, it will start with different color.

How do I change the state of the colour everytime the renderRow been called. I try to add a setState but it cause maximum call stack error..

```js
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
  this.state = {
      color: null,
  }
}

componentWillMount() {
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1);
    this.setState({ color: rand});
  }

  _renderRow ( rowData, rowId, rowColumn) {
    var temp=(this.state.color+1)%8;
    this.setState({color: temp});
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: backColor[temp] ,paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 10, marginBottom: 10, borderRadius: 5 }}>
        <Text>{rowData.name}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

 render() {

    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
        style={styles.mainContainer}
      />
    );
  }

}
```

anyone can point me into the right direction ?

Comment: The problem is that all the rows are using the same references of `color`, so when one row changes it, the child rows need to re-render, and in doing so, modify `color` too. Moving the `_renderRow` component out to a proper sub-component that manages its own colour based on a static input from the parent will fix the issue.

Comment: oh.. I see.. alright.. I'll try as you suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

basically I'm following what Andrew suggested..

I create a subcomponent that store the view and I call from the parent and send props.. and to randomize the colours I just shuffle the array that contain the colour and everything working perfectly.

something like this :-

```js
render() {
    this.shuffle(backColor);
    var card =[];

    for(var i=0;i<inspirationArr.length;i++) {
      card.push(<CardBoard color={backColor[i%8]} name={arr[i].name} />);
    }

    return <ScrollView style={styles.mainContainer}>{card}</ScrollView>;
}

class CardBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: props.color,
      name: props.name,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.color }}>
        <Text style={styles.nameText}>{this.state.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you.